# Show that $st$, $(s^2-t^2)/2$ and $(s^2+t^2)/2$ are relatively prime.

Tags: number-theory

Let $s$ and $t$ be odd integers. Show that $st$, $(s^2-t^2)/2$ and $(s^2+t^2)/2$ are relatively prime.

I've seen this question on here, but unfortunately some of the cases were not covered, and I want to confirm that the way I'm proving it is correct because it is not identical to the answers I saw.

The cases I'm interested in are ($st, (s^2-t^2)/2$) and $(st, (s^2+t^2)/2)$

For ($st, (s^2-t^2)/2$), let $p|st$ and $p|(s^2-t^2)/2$

- we know that s and t are odd, so p cannot be 2 because $p|st$
- For any other p, we know that $p|s$ or $p|t$ but not both at the same time.
- also we know that  $p|(s-t)(s+t)/2$, so either $p|s-t$ or $p|s+t$ both of which are impossible because p cannot divide s and t at the same time.

For ($st, (s^2+t^2)/2$), let $p|st$ and $p|(s^2+t^2)/2$

EDIT:

Can I say that $p|(s^2+t^2)/2$ => $p|(s^2+t^2)$ => $p|s^2$ and $t|s^2$ => $p|s$ and $p|t$? 
And can I use the same argument for the ($st, (s^2-t^2)/2$) case?

Comment: so what though? can't it be divisible by 2 and also by a prime? like 10 is even and it's divisible by 2 and a prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, one should specify that $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime. We show that $st$ and $\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}$ are relatively prime.  Note that since $s$ and $t$ are odd, it follows that $s^2+t^2$ is even, and therefore $\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}$ is an integer.

Suppose to the contrary that $st$ and $\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}$ are not relatively prime. Then there is a prime $p$ that divides both of them. It follows that $p$ divides one of $s$ and $t$. By symmetry, we may without loss of generality assume that $p$ divides $s$.

Since $p$ divides $\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}$, there is an integer $k$ such that $2pk=s^2+t^2$. It follows that $p$ divides $s^2+t^2$. Since $p$ divides $s^2$, it follows that $p$ divides $t^2$, and therefore $p$ divides $t$. This contradicts the fact that $s$ and $t$ are relatively prime.